# Snap mouse cursor to grid and/or objects

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have found a couple of fiddles where users can drag fabric objects and they snap to either a grid or other objects, however, I am not able to find any examples where user mouse cursor snaps to a grid or the border of existing object.

Is it possible, and if yes, is it done?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that there is no direct way to set the cursor position from JavaScript.

For your situation (as long as the grid spacing is not to big) you can set the `element.style.cursor = "url('pointer.png') 9 26, pointer"` and  change the last two numbers (hot spot) to move the mouse relative to itself. As the hotspot remains fixed the mouse will appear to snap to a coordinate but the hot spot will move.

```
var grid = 16;
// assume mouseX, mouseY are mouse coords.
var offsetX = mouseX % grid;
var offsetY = mouseY % grid;
// element is the element you are listening to mouse events from 
// pointer.png is an image of the cursor
element.style.cursor = "url('pointer.png') "+ offsetX + " " + offsetY + ", pointer"
```

Alternatively

Keep the hotspot and use a small offscreen canvas to draw the cursor offset by the correct amount. Then use `canvas.toDataURL` to create the cursor style URL.

- Note A. that both these methods do not move the mouse position and are only visuale. The mouse will still report its real position. You will have to adjust your mouse event listeners to compensate for the offset.
- Note B. the mouse will trigger mouseout and mouse over events even though visually the mouse has not entered or left the element. You will need to have a fix to deal with that (ie listen to the mouse via the body not the element).
- Note C. To stop the cursor flicking between updates change the cursor via requestAnimationFrame and not in the mouse events.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I asked this question I tried to generalize so that someone else might use the information, however, it looks like these methods will not work for my situation. More details: imagine a picture that has lines in different angles. I need to be able to draw lines with fabric.js (see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/URWru/) and snap to the lines on the picture. My thought was to process the image and get the coordinates of the black pixels and then put those coordinates on the fabricjs canvas and have mouse cursor snap to those coordinates.

Comment: Your "small offscreen canvas" gave me an idea. Please confirm if this is what you meant. What if we have a shape that follows the cursor - like in this (https://jsfiddle.net/ut4c25k6/) when you click on the object - and when the object is near some specific coordinate, then the object would jump to that coordinate away from the mouse. And if user would click while that object is away, then the 2nd line point would be red from the object and not from the mouse. Does it make sense?! :) Though I don't know if the technology allows something like that.